# Growpart throws unexpected error "unexpected output in sfdisk --version"

Tags: i18n, growpart

I am trying to grow GPT table for enlarged QEMU virtual disk. But when running `growpart`, it throws:

```
~ growpart /dev/sda 2
unexpected output in sfdisk --version [sfdisk，来自 util-linux 2.36.2]
```

Where is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies at the fact that I am using `zh_CN.UTF8` as locale. `growpart` checks `sfdisk`'s output but didn't take other languagues in consideration.

To mitigate this, just add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` at the beginnning:

```
~ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo growpart /dev/sda 2
[sudo] password for root:
CHANGED: partition=2 start=1026048 old: size=187717599 end=188743647 new: size=535844831 end=536870879
```